# Getting all my posts for a specific period (lambda expression)

Tags: asp.net, lambda

I would like a lambda expression to get all my posts with a PublishDate in a specific month / year range (like 10/2011).

```
public IEnumerable<Post> SearchPosts(string periode)
{
    // periode may be 10/2011 so I would like all posts from 10/01/2011 to 10/31/2011
    return m_PostRepository.GetPosts().Where(x => x.PublishDate...?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try it like this (working with `PublishDate` as `Nullable<DateTime>`):

```
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    var result = m_PostRepository.GetPosts().Where(x => x.PublishDate.HasValue && 
        x.PublishDate.Value.Month == date.Month && 
        x.PublishDate.Value.Year == date.Year).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Description

You can do this using the `DateTime` properties `Year` and `Month` in your `Where` Filter.

#### Sample

```
return m_PostRepository.GetPosts().Where(x => x.PublishDate.Year == 2011 &&
                                              x.PublishDate.Month == 10).ToList();
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - DateTime.Month Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.month.aspx)
- [MSDN - DateTime.Year Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.year.aspx)

### Update after a comment from Bronzato

```
DateTime? date;
// does date has a value ? If yes, apply the filter. If not return everything.
if (date.HasValue)
{
    return m_PostRepository.GetPosts().Where(x => x.PublishDate.Year == date.Value.Year &&
                                                  x.PublishDate.Month == date.Value.Month).ToList();
} else return return m_PostRepository.GetPosts();
```

Comment: @sebacipo: Thanks but I forgot to say that my PublishDate is a nullable type so PublishDate.Year is not recognised as it. Any suggestion?

Comment: @sebacipo Assuming i understand your comment (apply the filter only if your `date` has a value) my answer should be right.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public IEnumerable<Post> SearchPosts(string periode){

string[] _periode = periode.Split("/");
return m_PostRepository.GetPosts().Where(x => x.PublishDate.year = convert.ToInt16(_periode[1])).Where(x => x.PublishDate.Month= convert.ToInt16(_periode[0]))}
```